# How do I add my own API to an QnA maker using Azure? (LMS API)

Tags: azure, api, azure-web-app-service, chatbot

I am trying to make a QnA maker bot that can answer questions regarding hospitality (greeting the guest, get reservation details, etc..). So far, I created a QnA bot using azure which can answer simple questions that are within the Knowledge Base. My question is how do I implement an API that can answer these questions?

So far, I created an API management service in azure but I'm not too sure as to how to implement it into my bot.

I'm also following this documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/add-api-manually
If anyone can point in the right direction, I would appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

The document that you are trying to follow will help to create an API management service manually.
Alternatively you can follow this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/QnAMaker/quickstarts/quickstart-sdk?tabs=v1,version-1&pivots=rest) to create and query your knowledge base by  using SDK and  Rest API.

For more information Please refer the Below links:

[How to call Rest API for QnA maker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cognitiveservices-qnamaker/).

[Git-hub Sample.](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-REST-api-samples).